# Write Loop To Perform Function through Column Names

Tags: r, loops, apply

I have a dataset with a quantitative column for which I want to calculate the mean based on groups.  The other columns in the dataset are titled [FY2001,FY2002,...,FY2018].  These columns are populated with either a 1 or 0.

I want to calculate the mean of the first column for each of the FY columns when they equal 1. So, I want 18 different means.

I am used to using macros in SAS where I can replace parts of a dataset name or column name using a let statement.  This is my attempt at writing a loop in R to solve this problem:

```
vector = c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10",
         "11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18")
varlist = paste("FY20", vector, sep = "")

abc = for (i in length(varlist)){
    table(ALL_FY2$paste(varlist)[i])
}
abc
```

This doesn't work since it treats the paste function as a column.  What am I missing?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `[[` instead of `&` i.e. `table(ALL_FY2[[varlist[i]]])`.  However, the `abc <-` is wrong.  It would be `abc <- vector("list", length(varlist)); for(i in seq_along(varlist)) abc[[i]] <- table(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `[[` instead of `&` to subset the column.  In addition, 'abc' should be a `list` which gets assigned with the corresponding `table` output of each column in the `for` loop.

```
abc <- vector("list", length(varlist)) # initialize a `list` object
```

Loop through the sequence of 'varlist' and not the `length(varlist)` (it is a single number)

```
for(i in seq_along(varlist)) abc[[i]] <- table(ALL_FY2[[varlist[i]]])
```

---

However, if we need to have a single `table` output from all the columns mentioned in the 'varlist', `unlist` the columns to a `vector` and `rep`licate the sequence of columns before applying the `table`

```
ind <- rep(seq_along(varlist), each = nrow(ALL_FY2))
table(ind, unlist(ALL_FY2[varlist]))
```